# opnsips start gives " ERROR:core:main_loop: failed to fork module processes" and exits

Tags: ubuntu, opensips

starting opensips in aws t2 micro ( t2.micro Variable ECUs, 1 vCPUs, 2.5 GHz, Intel Xeon Family, 1 GiB memory, EBS only)  in ubuntu gives " ***ERROR:core:main_loop: failed to fork module processes***" and exits.

The command to run it
 opensips -d -f /etc/opensips/opensips.cfg -E

I checked disk space and enough of it left to install opensips

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            492M   12K  492M   1% /dev
tmpfs           100M  356K   99M   1% /run
/dev/xvda1      7.8G  2.9G  4.5G  39% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            497M     0  497M   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
```

Also the opensips traces on startup

```
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] NOTICE:core:main: version: opensips 2.2.7 (x86_64/linux)
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:main: using 32 Mb shared memory
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:main: using 2 Mb private memory per process
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_CORE_THRESHOLD(0)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_CORE_SHM_THRESHOLD(1)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_CORE_PKG_THRESHOLD(2)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:tm:mod_init: TM - initializing...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:sl:mod_init: Initializing StateLess engine
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] NOTICE:signaling:mod_init: initializing module ...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:mod_init: initializing UDP-plain protocol
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:mod_init: initializing TCP-plain protocol
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:rr:mod_init: rr - initializing
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:maxfwd:mod_init: initializing...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:sipmsgops:mod_init: initializing...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:usrloc:ul_init_locks: locks array size 512
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_UL_AOR_INSERT(3)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_UL_AOR_DELETE(4)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_UL_CONTACT_INSERT(5)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_UL_CONTACT_DELETE(6)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_UL_CONTACT_UPDATE(7)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:registrar:mod_init: initializing...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:avpops:avpops_init: initializing...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:textops:mod_init: initializing...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:cfgutils:mod_init: no hash_file given, disable hash functionality
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:cfgutils:mod_init: module initialized, pid [3162]
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:db_postgres:mod_init: initializing...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:db_text:dbt_init: using database at: /etc/opensips/dbtext
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] ERROR:dispatcher:ds_load_data: socket <null> is not local to opensips (we must listen on it) -> ignoring it
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_DISPATCHER_STATUS(8)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:permissions:parse_config_file: file not found: /etc/opensips/permissions.allow
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:permissions:mod_init: default allow file (/etc/opensips/permissions.allow) not found => empty rule set
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:permissions:parse_config_file: file not found: /etc/opensips/permissions.deny
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:permissions:mod_init: default deny file (/etc/opensips/permissions.deny) not found => empty rule set
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:dialog:mod_init: Dialog module - initializing
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:evi_publish_event: Registered event <E_DLG_STATE_CHANGED(9)>
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:uac:mod_init: initializing...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:exec:mod_init: exec - initializing
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:regex:mod_init: initializing module...
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] NOTICE:regex:mod_init: 'file' parameter is not set, group matching disabled
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:rest_client:mod_init: Module initialized!
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] WARNING:exec:exec_avp_fixup: You are using an obosolete function from the EXEC module!Please switch to the new exec() function
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:probe_max_sock_buff: using rcv buffer of 416 kb
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:probe_max_sock_buff: using snd buffer of 416 kb
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:init_sock_keepalive: TCP keepalive enabled on socket 9
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] ERROR:mi_datagram:mi_init_datagram_server: bind: No such file or directory
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] CRITICAL:mi_datagram:pre_datagram_process: function mi_init_datagram_server returned with error!!!
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] ERROR:core:start_module_procs: pre-fork function failed for process "MI Datagram" in module mi_datagram
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] ERROR:core:main_loop: failed to fork module processes
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3160] INFO:core:daemonize: pre-daemon process exiting with -1
root@inbound1:/etc/opensips# Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] INFO:core:cleanup: cleanup
Feb  8 07:24:32 [3162] NOTICE:core:main: Exiting....
```

So far couldnt find

Comment: There is something amiss with the "socket_name" setting of the "mi_datagram" module.  Can you post the relevant `opensips.cfg` section?

Comment: turns out it was the dbtext/dispatcher which was suppose to have specific headers like :  id(int,auto) setid(int) destination(string) socket(string,null) state(int) weight(int) priority(int) attrs(string) description(string)
1:1:sip\:x.x.x.x\:5060:null:2:1:1:'carrier':'description'